# How programmatically check if an activity is in fullscreen mode?

Tags: android, fullscreen

Or, more specifically, how to check if the statusbar is hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [Window class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html)'s method `getForcedWindowFlags()`.

Comment: Thanks, but looks like the method is protected, and I can not get it in my test class. I endup load the flags directly like this: int flags = getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes().flags